How to include MathJax in local Sphinx build without CDN?
I'm trying to include MathJax in my local _static Sphinx directory to avoid the overhead of downloading it on rebuilds while developing locally. I followed the instructions and set mathjax_path in conf.py as shown below, having copied tex-mml-chtml.js to docs/_static/MathJax/tex-mml-chtml.js as said in the Sphinx docs:
html_static_path = ["_static"]
mathjax_path = "MathJax/tex-mml-chtml.js"
mathjax3_config = {
    'loader': {'load': ['[tex]/mathtools']},
    'tex': {'packages': {'[+]': ['mathtools']}}
}

The usual make html build works if I do not set mathjax_path and let Sphinx use its defaults (downloading MathJax from a CDN). So using this example:
.. math::
    \begin{array}{l}
    f = \underbrace{x^3}_\textrm{text 1} + \underbrace{2}_\textrm{text 2}
    \end{array}

with the commented line in conf.py:
# mathjax_path = "MathJax/tex-mml-chtml.js"
mathjax3_config = {
    'loader': {'load': ['[tex]/mathtools']},
    'tex': {'packages': {'[+]': ['mathtools']}}
}

Gives the expected result:

And if I don't specify mathjax_path this is included in the HTML and it works:
<script>window.MathJax = {"loader": {"load": ["[tex]/mathtools"]}, "tex": {"packages": {"[+]": ["mathtools"]}}}</script>
<script defer="defer" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>



But if I uncomment # mathjax_path = "MathJax/tex-mml-chtml.js" MathJax doesn't work anymore, just giving the broken content of the :math: directive without rendering it:

this is included in the HTML:
<script>window.MathJax = {"loader": {"load": ["[tex]/mathtools"]}, "tex": {"packages": {"[+]": ["mathtools"]}}}</script>
<script defer="defer" src="_static/MathJax/tex-mml-chtml.js?v=cadf963e"></script>

What am I doing wrong? I compared the hash of the CDN distribution and my local file and they're the same. Should I have included a different file other than tex-mml-chtml.js? Should I have included more files like loader.js from MathJax? Because looking at the Sphinx docs it seems the paths are alright, I checked the build and the file is there in _static... I also searched for reported bugs for this functionality in the Sphinx repository but it seems there are none.

After checking the Firefox console for JS errors I noticed MathJax wasn't able to load some components locally. To get it to work locally with Sphinx I downloaded the whole MathJax library from GitHub via browser (there are other ways to get MathJax) and pointed mathjax_path to the specific script that MathJax chooses, in my use case (see the source HTML snippets in the question), when running from CDN namely es5/tex-mml-chtml.js.
Using an absolute path it's worth showing the syntax that worked for me on Windows in conf.py:
mathjax_path = "file:///C:/MathJax-master/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"


"other ways to get MathJax" links to documentation for an old version of MathJax.

@mzjn that document isn't obvious but the "current way" would be getting the master branch from GitHub.

I just thought it was strange that you link to documentation for MathJax 2.7.

Looks like these days it's mathjax/MathJax//es5/ that has the tex-mml-chtml.js (and the es5/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2 .woff fonts) https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/es5

Also, file:/// paths failed here; instead a path relative to the _static/ directory worked: git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax ./docs/_static/MathJax and then conf.py:mathjax_path = "MathJax/es5"
